# What is wrong with this list

Tags: list, python-2.7

```
coins=[100,50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]
n=10

for el in coins:
    if el>n:
        coins.remove(el)
print coins
```

The program above is supposed to remove all the elements in list **coins** which are greater than 10
The desired output is

```
[10, 5, 2, 1]
```

but i am getting

```
[50, 10, 5, 2, 1]
```

What is going wrong...

Comment: Python really ought to throw a "list modified during iteration" for stuff like this to avoid biting people...

Comment: I agree with you. This is really dangerous..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't alter a list while iterating over it. Try using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead:

```
coins = [el for el in coins if el <= n]
```

The reason you shouldn't remove elements while iterating is because it can result in other elements being skipped. For example, imagine that we want to remove `b` from the list `[a, b, c, d]`:

```
-----------------
| a | b | c | d |
-----------------
      ^ (we're on b)

-----------------
| a |   | c | d |
-----------------
      ^ (remove b)

-------------
| a | c | d |
-------------
      ^ (shift elements of list down to fill vacancy)

-------------
| a | c | d |
-------------
          ^ (step)
```

Notice that we skipped `c`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a while loop

```
while i < len(coins):
    if coins[i] > n:
        coins.pop(0)
    else:
        i+=1
```